# What does "maintain a legacy" mean?

Tags: meaning

> To deliver sporting competitions, as well as **maintain a legacy** for
>   residents and tourists, a variety of services are required.

I looked up a dictionary if legacy could be interpreted as "facilities", but couldn't find it. I think the below meaning would be the most appropriate for this context, but the definition is somewhat vague. What does "legacy" exactly mean in this context?

> something such as a tradition or problem that exists as a result of
>   something that happened in the past (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/legacy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider that to mean “maintain the existing services” or “maintain the existing provision”.